# How can the smallest absolute np.spacing value be smaller than the dtype eps?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand [this line from the np.spacing docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.spacing.html):

"It can be considered as a generalization of EPS: spacing(np.float64(1)) == np.finfo(np.float64).eps, and there should not be any representable number between x + spacing(x) and x for any finite x."

In my example, how can the smallest absolute np.spacing value be smaller than the np.float64 dtype eps?

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
a = np.random.uniform(size=10)
print(a.dtype)
float64
print(np.min(np.abs(np.spacing(a))))
1.3552527156068805e-20
print(np.finfo(np.float64).eps)
2.220446049250313e-16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eps` is the smallest value that can be added to `1` and make a difference.  Note the parameter `np.float64(1)` in their example.  Your uniform random numbers are less than 1, so the spacing value for those numbers is smaller.

The issue here is that a double-precision float only has 52 bits for its mantissa.  So, if two numbers differ by a factor of 2^53 (2 to the 53rd power), then adding the two does nothing -- the result is equal to the larger of the two.  That's what `spacing` returns -- the smallest number that makes a difference, but that smallest number depends on the starting number.  `spacing(1)` essentially returns 2^-52.  `spacing(0.0001)` returns a number 1000 times smaller.  If you pass in 2^53, then `spacing` returns 1, because adding 1 does not change the number.